# Getting an error: got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'

Tags: django, django-haystack

I was doing the Django haystack [tutorial](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html), and when I run the search query, I get the error `__call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'`. This error is coming from Django.

I am fairly new to Django, and I'm not sure what all to add to help debug this.

Also, in engine, I am using `haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine`, and am using ElasticSearch v7

Comment: It would probably help if you gave the full stack of the exception and also your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because Haystack does not support the latest version of ElasticSearch with Django. Migrated to Django Elasticsearch DSL